# Count non-empty values in array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter, array-filter

I tried the search already, but my problem was not solved there, since my case seems to be a bit different.

This is my array:

```
array(14) { [0]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(19) "Parge Lenis die ..." ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "05:51:23" } [1]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(8) "jiengels" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "05:51:18" } [2]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(3) ["name"]=> string(6) "n!n-oX" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "05:47:27" } [3]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(4) ["name"]=> string(8) "Maraskan" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "05:44:45" } [4]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(5) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "05:42:56" } [5]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(6) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "04:32:21" } [6]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(7) ["name"]=> string(5) "Heavy" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "03:29:39" } [7]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(8) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "02:59:28" } [8]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(9) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "02:54:37" } [9]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(10) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "02:53:33" } [10]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(11) ["name"]=> string(6) "Fischi" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "02:12:36" } [11]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(12) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "02:02:50" } [12]=> array(4) { ["index"]=> int(13) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["score"]=> int(0) ["time"]=> string(8) "01:09:53" } ["count"]=> int(13) }
```

Some of the entries have no value for "name" - therefore I only want to count those, which have a name.

But "array_filter" does not help at least how I tried to use it :( => array_filter($myarray);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_filter on the name colume like this, [live demo](https://eval.in/818276).

```
echo count(array_filter(array_column($array, 'name')));
```

Comment: I deleted my answer out of shame after seeing this :P This is a helpful approach to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter()` like below:

```
<?php

$array = array(
            array("index" => 1, "name" => "Parge Lenis die ..." , "score" => 0, "time" => "05:51:23"),
            array("index" => 2, "name" => "jiengels" , "score" => 0, "time" => "05:51:18"),
            array("index" => 3, "name" => "n!n-oX" , "score" => 0, "time" => "05:47:27"),
            array("index" => 4, "name" => "Maraskan" , "score" => 0, "time" => "05:44:45"),
            array("index" => 5, "name" => "" , "score" => 0, "time" => "05:42:56"),
            array("index" => 6, "name" => "" , "score" => 0, "time" => "04:32:21"),
            array("index" => 7, "name" => "Heavy" , "score" => 0, "time" => "03:29:39"),
        ); 

$array_non_empty = array_filter($array, function($item){
    return (isset($item['name']) && $item['name']) ? TRUE : FALSE;
});

$count_non_empty = count($array_non_empty); // number of non-empty values

echo $count_non_empty;
```

Comment: Unfortunatly there is not any ouput. I would need a count, like "5" - if there are 5 entries with a name.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use `count($array_non_empty)` to count non-empty values. @MrKayodoubleu